# how to create form that has multiple checkbox in hybris

Tags: jsp, jstl, sap-commerce-cloud

I have to create a form that has two radio buttons, one input field, I am able to create an input field but I'm not able to create radio buttons.
[image]

can anybody with experience with Hybris please help.

Comment: Add your code snippet in your question. It's pretty easy, there are a plethora of examples available on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the **path** attribute same for both radio button, so you will get the selected value in your submitted form.

Like

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="formElement" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/responsive/formElement" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<form:form id="yourFormId" commandName="yourForm" action="${request.contextPath}/submit/url" method="post">

    <form:radiobutton path="dataType" value="halfHrsData" label="Detailed Data" />
    <form:radiobutton path="dataType" value="monthlyData" label="Summary Data" />
    <formElement:formInputBox labelKey="email.label" path="email" />

    <button id="buttonId" type="submit" >
        <spring:theme code="submit.button"/>
    </button>

</form:form>
```

Comment: I prefer the use of items like this: <form:radiobuttons path="chosenItem" items="${itemList}"  />. Refer to https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-radiobutton-and-radiobuttons-example/ for a detailed example

Comment: @JohannesNolte - Yes, should use like that only if you have a set of data. I just demonstrated the example based on the questioner's input